# How does the memory allocation works when a reference of superclass is holding an object of subclass?

Tags: java

I went through all plausible answers relating to this question, but none answered what is the purpose of SuperClass ob = new SubClass()?

```
class SuperClass
{
    int x = 10;
    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("In Superclass: "+x);
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    int x = 20;
    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("In Sub Class: "+x);
    }
}

Class Main
{
    Public static void main (String args[])
    {
        SuperClass ob = new SubClass()
        System.out.println(ob.x); //prints 10
        ob.foo(); // print In Sub Class: 20
    }
}
```

I want to know:

1. How the memory allocation works in here
2. What is the purpose of SuperClass reference in holding the subclass object.

Comment: What do you mean by "How the memory allocation works in here"? What's the thing you're actually trying to understand?

Comment: Is the `SuperClass ob = new SubClass()` the line in question? This line is a pretty straightforward application of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Note that in memory (and in general), `ob` is _still_ a `SubClass`, and will act like a `SubClass`, but is simply referred to as a `SuperClass`. This is useful in cases where the underlying subclass in use may change, but the overall expected behavior remains the same (think `List` and `ArrayList`/`LinkedList`/etc). Java doesn't [slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object layout of the subclass is similar to this:

```
SubClass {
    meta-data
    SuperClass {
        meta-data
        int x
    }
    int x
}
```

In particular, notice that *there are two separate instances of `int x`*. Data members are not overloaded. Overloading only happens with methods. So `SubClass.foo()` overloads `SuperClass.foo()`, but `SubClass.x` only *hides* `SuperClass.x`.

When you print `ob.x`, you're telling the compiler to print `SuperClass.x` because the compiler only knows that `ob` is a `SuperClass` instance. On the other hand, if you call `ob.foo()` you're actually calling `SubClass.foo()` because this method is overridden.

The reason you would assign a subclass instance to a superclass reference variable is similar to why you should assign an object to an interface reference. It's to keep your code clean. If you don't need the specific methods that a subclass provides in addition to those of a superclass, you should make your variable a superclass reference. Then you're free to change the implementation class in just one place. Google "program to an interface, not to an implementation" for more details.